# Increasing scala/java heap size in scala shell script

Tags: scala, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have a scala shell script with the following header:

```
#! /bin/sh
env JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx20g"
exec scala -classpath ./target/scala-2.9.1/classes:lib/* "$0" "$@"
!#
```

Unfortunately, no matter how I set the JAVA_OPTS variable, the program terminates with an out of memory error.

How do I properly configure heap size in such a shell script without messing with global JAVA_OPTS environment variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Scala help:

> Options to scala which reach the java runtime:
>
> ...
>
> -J<arg>             -J is stripped and  passed to java as-is

So, you can add `-J-Xmx20g` argument to scala.

Answer (score 1):

Provide command line options for JVM that is used by Scala REPL:

```
$ env JAVACMD=JAVA JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024M -Xms16M -Xss16M" scala
```

Verify from REPL:

```
val r = Runtime.getRuntime
println("Memory usage: "+ (r.totalMemory - r.freeMemory) + " of " + r.maxMemory)
```

Memory usage: 66712264 of 954728448

Comment: Scala part computes properly but I get: `!#: not found` and `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: Link is outdated.